# Windows 10 Not Finding All Files, Even After Indexing

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 is not finding all files with a given string that I type into the Search box in Explorer. It is only giving me a partial (incomplete) list, but there are more files that satisfy my search.

Example: there are thousands of files with the string "*resume*" somewhere in the filename, but Explorer Search only brings back a dozen or so.

I have tried re-building all indexing, even by removing some disks that I don't need to make it faster. I always wait till the end to make sure the indexing is 100% completed.

My steps:

1. Control Panel -> Indexing Options
2. Ensure my disk is listed (in my case, D:, **an external WD-Passport hard drive**)
3. Just to be sure, I click Advanced.
4. Under File Types, I make sure all extensions are included, there are thousands and they're all selected.
5. I click the **Rebuild** button to do it again.
6. After a while, the rebuilding is complete.
7. Result: Windows 10 still not listing all my files for a given string.

I'm not to sure what else to do at this point. Is this a bug? Is it an issue with the WD Passport external drive?